proving the given series is irrational
I want to prove this problem : 
m is an integer grater than 2 than the series
$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{m^{n^2}}$$
is irrational. And i want to use this theorem:
Let $a > 1$ be a real number. Suppose that for some real number $\beta$
there are infinitely many rational numbers $h,k$ such that $|\beta - \frac{h}{k}|<k^{-a}$ . Then $\beta$ is irrational.
Firstly, this series is convergent since the geometric series $\sum \limits _{n=0} ^{\infty} (\frac{1}{m})^n $ is convergent where $|\frac{1}{m} |<1$ and $\sum\limits _{n=0} ^{\infty} \frac{1}{m^{n^2}} <  \sum \limits_{n=0} ^{\infty} \frac{1}{m^n}$. So, the original series is convergent by comparison test. Now, let $\beta = \sum \limits_{n=0} ^{\infty} \frac{1}{m^{n^2}}$ and $\sum \limits_{n=0} ^{k} \frac{1}{m^{n^2}} = \frac{p_k}{q_k}$ where $q_k = {m^{k^2}}$ . So consider:
\begin{align*}
|\beta - \frac{p_k}{q_k}| =  \sum \limits_{n=k+1} ^{\infty} \frac{1}{m^{n^2}} 
< \sum \limits_{n=k+1} ^{\infty} \frac{1}{m^{(k+1)^2}}
\end{align*}
But i stuck here. Could you help me?

Have a look at this very recent paper doi:10.31559/glm2024.14.3.2

This is a non-terminating non-repeating decimal in base $m$ and hence an irrational number.

See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2128641/72031

If there were a real number $a>1$ for which
$$\sum_{n=k+1}^\infty\frac1{m^{n^2}}<\left(\frac1{m^{k^2}}\right)^{-a},$$
then the last equation in your post would be enough to finish the problem. However, this is not true: for any $a>1$, the right side $m^{-ak^2}$ is smaller than the first term $m^{-(k+1)^2}$ alone, when $k$ is large enough. So, the theorem you've mentioned isn't strong enough to solve the problem.
So, you want to use something stronger. Here is a stronger version of your theorem.
Theorem. Suppose that, for every positive integer, there exists a pair $(h,k)$ so that
$$0<\left\lvert \beta-\frac hk\right\rvert\leq\frac1{kd}.$$
Then $\beta$ is irrational.
A proof of this theorem is hidden in the following spoiler-tag:

 Suppose for the sake of contradiction that $\beta=p/q$ for some integers $p$ and $q$. Then, for any rational $h/k$, either $\beta=h/k$ or
 $$\left\lvert\beta-\frac hk\right\rvert=\left\lvert\frac{pk-hq}{kq}\right\rvert=\frac{\lvert pk-hq\rvert}{kq}\geq\frac1{kq}.$$
 So, we obtain a contradiction from the rational number $h/k$ we get from the theorem statement when $d=q+1$.

This is rather stronger than the theorem you listed: if we have a sequence $p_k/q_k$ of rational approximations of $\beta$ (which are not themselves equal to $\beta$), we only need that $q_k\lvert\beta-p_k/q_k\rvert$ tends to zero, not that $q_k^a\lvert\beta-p_k/q_k\rvert$ is bounded for some power $a$ strictly greater than one. It turns out that the approximation to your series with $q_k=m^{k^2}$ is good enough to use this theorem. This is worked out in the following spoiler tag.

 What we need to show is that, for every $d>0$, there exists some $k$ for which
 $$\sum_{n=k+1}^\infty\frac1{m^{n^2}}\leq\frac1{d\cdot m^{k^2}}.$$
 We upper-bound the series by
 $$\sum_{n=k+1}^\infty\frac1{m^{n^2}}\leq\sum_{n=k+1}^\infty\frac1{m^{(k+1)^2+(n-k-1)}}=\frac1{m^{(k+1)^2}}\cdot\left(1+\frac1m+\frac1{m^2}+\cdots\right)\leq \frac2{m^{(k+1)^2}}.$$
 So, it suffices for
 $$\frac2{m^{(k+1)^2}}\leq\frac1{d\cdot m^{k^2}}.$$
 This rearranges to $m^{2k+1}\geq 2d$. Since $m>1$, this holds for large enough $k$.

